# Haskell | Assigning multiple values to something so they could be passed to a function as a single argument

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to "assign" and pass values in Haskell in the following way:

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo x y = x + y

bar :: ??
bar = 2 3 -- ??

foo bar == 5
```

Foo is some function that takes two ints. I want to assign those ints to a single bar and pass that bar to foo so that it could yield it's result. I would like to achieve this without using tuples, new types or value separation like this:

```
bar1 = 2
bar2 = 3
foo bar1 bar2 == 5
```

This question is out of curiosity and not any practical reason.

Comment: You do not design something to a variable, you declare a variable, that is something different.

Comment: You could define a function `withbar x = x 2 3`, and then use `withbar foo`.

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: You don't want to use tuples, but that's exactly what is needed here, together with (un)currying.

Answer (score 5):

There's the sane answer:

```
Data.Tuple.uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
data A; data B; data C
foo :: A -> B -> C
bar :: (A, B)
uncurry foo bar :: C
```

There's the eccentric answer:

```
bar :: (A -> B -> c) -> c
bar f = f A B
bar foo :: C
```

There's the cheating answer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
#define bar A B
foo bar :: C
-- expansion: foo A B :: C
-- Don't try to use this in any other way!
-- (bar, 2) ~> (A B, 2) -> error
-- It's incredibly unhygienic and WILL explode at some point
-- You probably want to uppercase the name to make it stick out
-- Or maybe
#undef bar
#define AP2(x) (fst (x)) (snd (x))
bar :: (A, B)
foo AP2(bar) :: C
#define BAR AP2(bar)
foo BAR :: C
-- expansion: foo (fst (A, B)) (snd (A, B))
```

There's the dependent answer (which is just a boosted `uncurry`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, FunctionalDependencies, GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}

data HList (xs :: [*]) where
  Hil :: HList '[]
  Hons :: x -> HList xs -> HList (x : xs)

class AppHList f (a :: [*]) r | f a -> r where
  appHList :: f -> HList a -> r
instance AppHList x '[] x where
  appHList x Hil = x
instance (f ~ (a -> b), a ~ x, AppHList b xs r) => AppHList f (x : xs) r where
  appHList f (Hons x xs) = appHList (f x) xs

-- if it's not obvious, HLists of two elements are isomorphic to 2-tuples
-- toT (Hons a (Hons b Hil)) = (a, b)
-- toH (a, b) = (Hons a (Hons b Hil))
-- toT . toH = id = toH . toT
-- and we get
-- uncurry = (. toH) . appHList
-- so, on some level, they are the same

bar :: HList [A, B]
bar = Hons A$Hons B$Hil
appHList foo bar :: C
```

There's the *unhinged* answer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, FlexibleInstances, GADTs, TypeOperators #-}
import GHC.TypeLits

class FooType t
  foo :: t
-- GADTs is only here for the ~s, and they aren't really needed
-- They're only here to make foo (B, A) a "needed (A, B) got (B, A)"
-- instead of a "instance not found"
instance (a ~ A, b ~ B) => FooType ((a, b) -> C) where
  foo (a, b) = foo a b 
instance FooType (A -> B -> C) where
  foo a b = _
-- This instance pulls in GHC.TypeLits, DataKinds, TypeOperators, and UndecidableInstances
-- all in the name of pretty error messages.
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} TypeError (Text "foo is a function from "
                                    :<>: ShowType A
                                    :<>: Text " and "
                                    :<>: ShowType B
                                    :<>: Text " to "
                                    :<>: ShowType C
                                    :$$: Text "It may not be given the type "
                                    :<>: ShowType t
                                         ) => FooType t where
  foo = undefined
```

There's the real answer:

No. The simple and utter fact is that `foo` has two `(->)`s in its type, and that means you need two function applications to consume it completely. There are various tricks (in order, `uncurry`, continuation passing style, going outside the language to circumvent its rules, funky pseudo-dependently-typed "fun stuff", and overloading `foo`) to move this burden somewhere else (resp. in `uncurry`'s definition, in `bar`'s definition, in the expanded post-CPP code, in `appHList`, in one of the instances of `FooType`) but none of them really achieve what you want. (CPS is backwards and notoriously hard to read, CPP is just broken, and the typeclass thing requires massively modifying `foo` (most of the language extensions were just for effect; sue me), and `uncurry` and its fancier cousin `appHList` require an extra function call).

Comment: E[cc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#v:callCC)entric pun intended?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your example of `foo bar == 5` to work, you need to make sure the types match...

`foo` takes two `Int`s and returns an `Int` and has type `foo :: Int -> (Int -> Int)`. The brackets aren't strictly necessary but I've added them in for clarity (`->` is right-associative).

You can see from this that your example won't work. You're trying to pass a function `bar` as the first argument where it's actually expecting an `Int`. The only way this would work is if `bar` returned an `Int` in which case you would only be able to pass in one variable.

Because of the bracketing above, you can't give `foo` an `(Int -> Int)` as an argument. This would be the only way to pass in two variables without tuples or something else but isn't possible.

So unfortunately, I think the best way to achieve this would be with tuples and perhaps `uncurry` as suggested. Interesting question though!